# Append option in select and add data attribute to option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select name slc_pc and i want to append option by jquery code.

I try these script. But it's not working.

```
$("select[name='slc_pc']").append(new Option("Hello", "Hello", true, true).attr("abc",brand,"123",model));
```

Comment: please add all relevant code to OP

Comment: @guradio i don't understand

Comment: `attr("abc",brand,"123",model)` is invalid. You need to pass object for multiple attributes. `attr("abc": brand, "123": model)` assuming those two variables are defined.

Comment: @Tushar can you make answer for my question?

Comment: @Tushar not define : symbol

Comment: Do you want to add `brand` & `model` as attributes are `abc` & `123`?

Comment: yes i want to add two attribute data-brand="abc", data-nodel="123"

Comment: `$('select[name="slc_pc"]').append($('<option />').val('Hello').text('Hello').prop('selected', true).data({brand: 'abc', model: '123'}))`

Comment: @Tushar : yes that working can you create answer i will make it correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. First of all, to set multiple attributes, you need to pass them as an object. Second, the property name and value for the `data` attributes are incorrect. `brand` & `model` should be property and `abc` & `123` should be their values respectively.

`new Option` will create an option element which does not have `attr` method on it. You may use jQuery to create a new element.

Here's the correct way

```js
$('select[name="slc_pc"]')
  .append($('<option />')  // Create new <option> element
    .val('Hello')            // Set value as "Hello"
    .text('Hello')           // Set textContent as "Hello"
    .prop('selected', true)  // Mark it selected
    .data({                  // Set multiple data-* attributes
      brand: 'abc',
      model: '123'
    })
  );
```

Comment: What do .data({            
      brand: 'abc',
      model: '123'
    })

Comment: @ShneorBachar It sets the `data-*` attributes with given values.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an ID "slc-pc" to your select element, it's like this in it's basic form:

```
$('#slc_pc').append($("<option></option>").attr({"value": key, "abc": brand, "123": model }).text(value));
```

Comment: You missed two more attributes. Update answer as `.attr({"value": key, "abc": brand, "123": model })`

Comment: What do .data({ brand: 'abc', model: '123' })??

Answer (score 1):

try this one

you have add `)` after `(new Option("Hello", "Hello", true, true)` that and remove `)` from last

```js
$("select[name='slc_pc']").append(new Option("Hello", "Hello", true, true)).attr("abc", "brand", "123", "model");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='slc_pc'>
  <option>select</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    var brand = 'test';
    var model = '123';
    
    var brand1 = 'abc';
    var model1 = '456';
  
   $(".slc_pc").append("<option value='hello' data-brand='" +brand+ "' data-model='" +model+ "'>hello</option><option value='hello1' data-brand='" +brand1+ "' data-model='" +model1+ "'>hello1</option>");
})

$(document).on("change",".slc_pc", function(){
   var option = $("option:selected", this);
   alert("value : "+ $(this).val() + ", brand : "+$(option).data('brand') + ", model : " + $(option).data('model'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<select class='slc_pc' name='slc_pc'>
    <option value=''>--select--</option>
</select>
```

it can be done by something like this.